# python3 yahoo earnings calendar

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, yahoo

There's a package that helps fetch data https://github.com/wenboyu2/yahoo-earnings-calendar and it works on python2. But in python3 this raise errors, so I can make conclusion that this package does not support python3. I just need this 2 following functions:

```
    print yec.earnings_on(date_from)
    print yec.earnings_between(date_from, date_to)
```

because they returns necessary information. Is it exists some decisions of this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried/found so far to get around your problem?

Comment: I tryied to edit files of yahoo_earnings_package for python3. Also I found fix version for python3 but it did not work due to missing arguments.